# From eclipse to phonegap - signing android phonegap app

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, google-play, certificate

I have developed an app i eclipse, signed it and uploaded it to google play. I still have the keystore on my computer.

Now i have turned my fate to phonegap and HTML development. And my eclipse Android app need to be replaced on google play.

My challenge is now when i use:

$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

and upload this to build.phonegap.com it works fine. But when i upload it to google play it says that the fingerprint do not match.

What am i doing wrong? I use the same keystore, the right alias and password. When i am using -genkey and filling out the first name and last name, city etc. i do not remember the original details. Is that the problem, do i have to be 100% correct in these details? is it important?

When i am signing with eclipse and upload to google play it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This was not easy to figure out but the solution was. It turns out that eclipse do not use the notation .keystore on the file keystore. The solution was to add .keystore in the keystore filename from eclipse. Thanks for your time.